# Cant store firebase storage image url to firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, imageurl

I'm writing a code to save data in firestore, but it saves other data without image url.

Here is my code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_learning_app/Models/notice.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_learning_app/Services/crud.dart';
    import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

    class NoticeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
    final firestoreService=FirestoreService();
     String _userName;
     String _userPost;
     String _date; 
     String _photoUrl;

     var uuid=Uuid();

    //setters

     changeUserName(String value){
     _userName=value;
     notifyListeners();
    }
     changeUserPost(String value){
     _userPost=value;
     notifyListeners();
    }
     changeDate(String value){
     _date=value;
     notifyListeners();
    }
     changePhotoUrl(value){
     _photoUrl=value;
     print('$photoUrl');
     notifyListeners();
       }

      //getters

     String get userName => _userName;
     String get userPost => _userPost;
     String get date => _date;
     String get photoUrl => _photoUrl;


     saveNotice(){

     print('$photoUrl');
     print('$userName');
      var newNotice=Notice(userName:userName,userPost:userPost,
     date:date,photoUrl:photoUrl , noticeId: uuid.v4());
       firestoreService.saveNotice(newNotice);

     }



      }
```

I think `saveNotice()` function is executing before `changePhotoUrl(value)` function, it print value to `username` but it prints `photourl`null, after that it prints url. I think it is the result of the print statement which is in `changePhotoUrl(value)`.

This is the place where  I get download photo url:

```
      File noticepic;
      Future getNotice()async{
      var tempImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
       setState(() {
         noticepic=tempImage ;
         });
        }
        uploadNotice()async{
       String fileName=basename(noticepic.path);
         final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef=FirebaseStorage().ref().child
      ('cisnotices/$fileName');
        final StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(noticepic);
         await task.onComplete;
         await firebaseStorageRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) {

           noticeProvider.changePhotoUrl(url.toString());
         });
      }
     NoticeProvider noticeProvider=NoticeProvider();
```

This is the place where I call getimage and upload image functions, then I called `saveNotice()` function:

```
         Padding( padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 280),
             child: Container(
             child: IconButton(

             icon:Icon(
             Icons.add_photo_alternate
             ),

       color: Colors.grey[700],

        iconSize: 40,

        onPressed:(){

        getNotice().then((f) async => await uploadNotice());


         }

             ),
                    ),
                         ),
         SizedBox(height:10.0),

                  Container(
                    height: 30.0,
                    width: 100.0,
                    child: RaisedButton(

                      onPressed: (){
                        noticeProvider.saveNotice();

                      },

                      child: Text('Upload'),
                      color: Colors.green[400],
                    ),
                  )
```

This is the output:

```
I/flutter (19698): null
I/flutter (19698): aja yogan
I/System.out(19698): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(19698): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(19698): tagSocket(116) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
I/System.out(19698): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out(19698): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/flutter (19698): https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/learningapp-313e5.appspot.com/o/cisnotices%2Fimage_picker5085188822864985108.jpg?alt=media&token=8eccc3c7-14b5-4820-916e-5f1e4a67954e
```

Comment: Can you try printing the URL once it's generated and try manually if the URL is working fine ? before and after converting to string. Also can you please try without all those extra styling info ? It might be something written wrongly there. Try to get the URL only working and then start adding back the rest as it will be much easier to locate the issue cause.